# Cannot move or delete files even after chown and chmod

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, permissions

I can't seem to be able to move or delete files in my home directory even after `chmod` and `chown`.

At first glance it seems like the permissions are set up correctly.

```
user@f9195084fbf8:~$ ls -lah
total 32K
drwxr-xr-x 18 user user 4.0K Oct  8 17:35 .
drwxr-xr-x 16 root root 4.0K Oct  8 04:57 ..
-rwxr-xr-x  1 user user  220 Apr  3  2012 .bash_logout
-rwxr-xr-x  1 user user 3.5K Apr  3  2012 .bashrc
drwxr-xr-x  2 user user 4.0K Oct  8 05:43 .matplotlib
drwxr-xr-x  2 user user 4.0K Oct  8 17:19 .pip
-rwxr-xr-x  1 user user  675 Apr  3  2012 .profile
drwxr-xr-x 15 user user 4.0K Oct  8 04:58 .virtualenvs
```

But I can't remove existing files.

```
user@f9195084fbf8:~$ rm .bashrc
rm: cannot remove `.bashrc': Operation not permitted
```

So I try `chown` and `chmod` but it still doesn't work.

```
user@f9195084fbf8:~$ sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP .
user@f9195084fbf8:~$ sudo chmod -R 755 .          
user@f9195084fbf8:~$ rm .bashrc
rm: cannot remove `.bashrc': Operation not permitted
user@f9195084fbf8:~$ mv .bashrc .virtualenvs/
mv: cannot move `.bashrc' to `.virtualenvs/.bashrc': Operation not permitted
```

However, I can write and remove newly created files just fine.

```
user@f9195084fbf8:~$ echo 'hello' > test.txt
user@f9195084fbf8:~$ ls  
test.txt
user@f9195084fbf8:~$ rm test.txt
```

Comment: Have you tried using  `./.bashrc` instead of `.bashrc` & `./.virtualenvs/` instead of `.virtualenvs/` ?

Comment: Wouldn't think that would make a difference, but just gave it a try now and same results.

Comment: This is a normal system? No funny mounts or mount options? What does `mount` say? What does `id` say? What about `getfacl .bashrc` and `ls -dZ . .bashrc`?

Comment: What are the permissions on the directory the files are in? In order to remove a file, you must have write permission on the directory containing the file.

Answer (score 4):

Any immutable attribute has been set on the file?

```
lsattr .bashrc
```

If so, you may fix it by:

```
chattr -i -a .bashrc
```

Run [`man chattr`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chattr) to see the flags, or check the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chattr).